# Alias to remove folder prefix from `ls` command

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, alias, ls

Sometimes `ls` will prefix file names with a folder name, other times it will not. The following you can duplicate on your platform:

```
$ ls /var/lib/initramfs-tools
4.10.10-041010-generic  4.4.0-78-generic       4.8.17-040817-generic
4.10.17-041017-generic  4.4.0-89-generic       4.9.0-040900-generic
4.11.12-041112-generic  4.4.33-040433-generic  4.9.21-040921-generic
4.11.3-041103-generic   4.4.8-040408-generic   4.9.40-040940-generic
4.11.9-041109-generic   4.6.3-040603-generic   4.9.8-040908-generic
4.12.0-041200-generic   4.7.5-040705-generic   4.9.9-040909-generic
4.12.4-041204-generic   4.8.12-040812-generic

$ ls /boot/vml*
/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.10-041010-generic  /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.8-040408-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.17-041017-generic  /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.3-040603-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-4.11.12-041112-generic  /boot/vmlinuz-4.7.5-040705-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-4.11.3-041103-generic   /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.12-040812-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-4.11.9-041109-generic   /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.17-040817-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-4.12.0-041200-generic   /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-040900-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-4.12.4-041204-generic   /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.21-040921-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-78-generic        /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.40-040940-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-89-generic        /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.8-040908-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.33-040433-generic   /boot/vmlinuz-4.9.9-040909-generic
```

I like the format of the first version that doesn't include the directory prefix `initramfs-tools/`. I feel the second version where `boot/` is added as a prefix is redundant.

I found this [Unix & Linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124887/is-it-possible-to-remove-folder-prefix-from-a-ls-command) with a similar request but the answers there are convoluted.

An alias would be preferable because I already have four `ls` aliases setup in `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'
```

Even if the alias was called `dir` I'd still use it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because of "pathname expansion" and is not related to the `ls`, before your `ls` commands get to run your "*" will be expanded to absolute path names, it's like you are running your command like this:

```
ls /path/to/file/1 /path/to/file/2 /path/to/file/3
```

#### Function

Create a function:

```
function myls() { basename -a "$@" ;}
```

#### Alias

or create an alias:

```
alias myls='basename -a'
```

---

Put it your `.bashrc` or somewhere else, then use it like this:

```
myls /boot/vml*
```

the output would be:

```
vmlinuz-4.9.0-3
...
```

Comment: That's a complicated way to do it. `myls () { basename -a "$@"; }` and then `myls /boot/vml*` is simpler.

Comment: Consider what will happen to filenames with spaces. Why use `$(ls)` at all?

Comment: Your output removed `/boot/vmlinuz-`. Removing `/boot/` is good :).  Removing `vmlinuz-` not so good :( Are you testing this on your actual `/boot` directory?

Comment: When `basename -a "$@"` is sufficient, then why ... ? Never mind.

Comment: @muru Oh my god ... :)) just send an answer and I'm free to go... I'm late :D What the hell I was thinking ... I wasn't thinking at all, I should get some sleep I guess :/

Comment: @Ravexina now your output shows `vmlinuz-4.9.0-3` and it is probably missing `-generic` after it or, `lowlatency` perhaps. In any case, are you running it on real data?, ie  an actual `/boot` directory? It looks like you are creating output to match what you think the program should output... I can't find a kernel version `4.9.0-3` in [Ubuntu Mainline Kernels](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I'm running under Debian right now, have you test it yourself? it should work fine.

Comment: @Ravexina I was thinking of installing Debian today and wondering what DE's are available for it. Sorry I didn't even know other Linux distro's didn't have a `/boot` directory just sort of thought it was universal, perhaps because `grub` has hooks into it and what not. I'll take your answer and test it in Ubuntu shortly.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Pretty much all DE's are available under Debian too, and also just like all other distributions, Debian  got a `/boot` directory too, however its Kernel naming convention is a little bit  differ from Ubuntu.

Comment: @Ravexina Duly noted. I've accepted your answer as you've not doubt noticed. It correctly answers the question however it doesn't have multiple columns making the screen lines greater which negates the spirit of the question which was brevity. However I firmly believe a better answer is not possible without hacking `/bin/ls` source code  and recompiling it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not `ls` that does that. It's the Bash shell. Replace your `ls` commands with `echo`, and see the "wildcard expansion" that bash does for you. By the time `ls` starts executing, all the wildcard expansion is done.

```
ls /var/lib/initramfs-tools
```

Passes `ls` the name of a directory (see `ls -d /var/lib/initramfs-tools`).

```
ls /boot/vml*
```

actually sees (on ***MY*** system, YMMV)

```
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ ls /boot/vml*
/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-83-generic  /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-87-generic  /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-89-generic
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ echo /boot/vml*
/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-83-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-87-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-89-generic
```

A list of files to `ls`.

What you want is not possible, sorry.

Comment: You didn't try the `echo /var/lib/initramfs-tools` which only returns the directory tree and none of the files. So `echo` is always not the same as `ls` command although it did work in the example you gave. Thanks for saying sorry it can't be done but I still have fingers crossed for a "Faint Hope Clause".

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix try `ls /var/lib/in*`, then. You'll see it still lists the full directory paths, which is what it got as arguments. The single directory argument is a special case.

Comment: @muru I noticed the distinction between a full sub-directory name and file name wild card before I posted the question. I just think one format looks better than the other. I also noticed you keep editing out the extended line draw characters in my PS output and replacing them with blanks.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix All that prompt nonsense is just noise when the output is short enough.

Comment: @muru One man's "noise" is another man's demarcation point I guess. I like the extended ASCII character set line much better than a blank line in the PS prompt. I think it gives a better visual representation between commands. But I'm not going to argue the point  *shrugs*.